# set Environment variable for OPC publisher

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, opc-ua, azure-iot-edge

i have an OPC-publisher module which i want to deploy as an iot edge module for this purpose i need to give connectionString. in the documentation given on github they have mentioned some environment variables which can be set for this purpose as follows:

There are a couple of environment variables which can be used to control the application:
    _HUB_CS:  sets the IoTHub owner connectionstring
    _GW_LOGP: sets the filename of the log file to use
    _TPC_SP:  sets the path to store certificates of trusted stations
    _GW_PNFP: sets the filename of the publishing configuration file

i want to know where to set them in a code, on azure portal where they provide an option for setting env variables, from command line, or in  dockerfile. 
any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at [this](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge-opc-publisher#using-it-as-a-module-container-in-azure-iot-edge)? It explains in detail how to run the OPC publisher as an Edge module. Just copying here for completeness:

```
 {
  "Hostname": "pub-test",
  "Cmd": [
      "publisher",
      "--pf=./pn.json",
      "--di=60",
      "--to",
      "--aa",
      "--si=0",
      "--ms=0"
  ],
  "HostConfig": {
      "PortBindings": {
          "62222/tcp": [{
              "HostPort": "62222"
          }]
      },
      "Binds": [
          "x509certstores:/root/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores",
          "d:/iiotedge:/appdata"
      ],
      "ExtraHosts": [
          "localhost:127.0.0.1",
          "opctestsvr:192.168.178.26"
      ]
  }
}
```